# Fast Date manipulation in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My application works a lot with timestamps. Very often, I need to cut off the `DDMMYYYY` part of a `Date` variable. The first guess is

```
Dim xDate as Date 
Dim xDDMMYYY as Date : xDDMMYYY = Dateserial(Year(xDate), Month(xDate), Day(xDate))
```

However, this is super slow. So instead, I would like to find a faster way. First, I would try to use the `Floor` function. So ...

```
Public Function timeStamp2DDMMYYYY(xStamp As Date) As Date
    timeStamp2DDMMYYYY = WorksheetFunction.Floor(CDbl(xStamp), 1)                                  
End Function
```

However, this produces a wrong result for e.g. Jan 4th, 1900 where the function returns Jan 3th, 1900. So, I give the second try...

```
Public Function timeStamp2DDMMYYYY(xStamp As Date) As Date
    ' timeStamp2DDMMYYYY = CDbl(xStamp) - modDblTimeStamps(CDbl(xStamp), 1)              ' Cut the non-whole days off
     timeStamp2DDMMYYYY = WorksheetFunction.Floor(CDbl(xStamp), 1)                             ' Cut the non-whole days off
End Function

Private Function modDblTimeStamps(xA As Double, xB As Double) As Double
    Dim xRes As Double:   xRes = xA - (CLng(xA / xB) * xB)
    If (xRes < -1 / 86400) Then xRes = xRes + xB    ' A difference between xRes and zero
                                                    ' must be at least one second to prevent
    modDblTimeStamps = xRes
End Function
```

However, this produces bad behavior for e.g. Aug 31, 1963 23:59:59.

My question is : is there a fast and failsafe way to accomplish this conversion?

**EDIT**
By bad - I should have used the profiler first. For comparison purposes I gathered all the proposed solutions:

```
Public Function timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_1(xStamp As Date) As Date
    timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_1 = DateSerial(Year(xStamp), Month(xStamp), Day(xStamp))
End Function

Public Function timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_2(xStamp As Date) As Date
    timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_2 = DateValue(xStamp)
End Function

Public Function timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_3(xStamp As Date) As Date
    Dim xDDMMYYY As String: xDDMMYYY = DatePart("d", xStamp) & "." & DatePart("m", xStamp) & "." & DatePart("yyyy", xStamp)
    timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_3 = CDate(xDDMMYYY)
End Function

Public Function timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_4(xStamp As Date) As Date
    timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_4 = CDate(Split(xStamp, Chr(32))(0))
End Function

Public Function timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_5(xStamp As Date) As Date
    timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_5 = CDbl(xStamp) - modDblTimeStamps(CDbl(xStamp), 1)               
End Function

Public Function timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_6(xStamp As Date) As Date
   timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_6 = Int(xStamp)
End Function
```

Going from 01.01.1900 to 31.12.1905 with a 5 minute increment, all functions return the right value. The profiling results are :

```
timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_1 - 2.22199s
timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_2 - 5.62594s
timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_3 - 5.91005s
timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_4 - 6.51989s
timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_5 - 3.67998s
timeStamp2DDMMYYYY_6 - 4.29623s
```

Conclusion - my slow spot is somewhere else in the timeStampManip module. The primitive version is the fastest... Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Super slow compared to what? I did a million iterations in .9 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DatePart function.

I don't think it's possible to combine multiple requests in one DatePart function. The function returns an integer for one request at a time.

In other words, instead of `xDDMMYYY = DatePart("dnyyyy", xDate)` you'd have to request one by one:

```
Dim xDate As Date
Dim xDDMMYYY As String
xDDMMYYY = DatePart("d", xDate) _
  & DatePart("n", xDate) _
  & DatePart("yyyy", xDate)
```

Notice I defined xDDMMYYY as a string, not a date. DatePart returns integers, so you'll have to do a bit of string manipulation to get it to display how you'd like. Again, this is a builtin function for dealing with date/time-stamps, so it'll be the most failsafe method of getting reliable results.

Comment: To select a part of the date, for example the hour: `=DatePart("H",xDate)`. This function is built in the VBA language, so it will be the most failsafe.

Comment: DatePart("dd.mm.yyyy", xStamp) does not seem to work, but honestly, I guess the function parses the string and if "yyyy" is found, Year(xDate) is called, hence speed improvements are not going to happen.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain how to use this function further.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to strip off time and leave only a pure date then:

```
Public Function StripTime(dIn As Date) As Date
    StripTime = Int(dIn)
End Function
```

tested with:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim d As Date, d2 As Date
    d = DateValue("1/18/1900") + TimeValue("9:35 PM")
    MsgBox d
    d2 = StripTime(d)
    MsgBox (d2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Gray's Student, thanks. However this does not work for a timestamp with time larger than lunchtime...

Comment: You can just use the DateValue function by itself to strip away time: `xDDMMYYY = DateValue(xDate)`. This will return a date, but you could use the Format function to format it to the DDMMYYY format.